# JavaScript code not executed when I press "submit button"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript code which calculates the total cost of accomodation, but whenever i run it it doesn't work.

I have tried debugging the code but I can't seem to find any problems.

Can you please help me fix this code.

This is JavaScript and the HTML is below it:

```
function calcStayCost(pricePerNight, numberOfNights) {
  return pricePerNight * numberOfNights
}

function calcDiscount(numNights, standardCost) {
  var dRate;

  if (numberOfNights < 5) {
    dRate = 0
  } else {
    if (numberOfNights >= 5 && numberOfNights <= 10) {
    dRate = 0.03
  } else {
    dRate = 0.05
  }
  }
  return dRate;
}

function calcAmount(cost, discount) {
  return cost - discount;
}

function validateInput(validNumber) {
  if (validNumber > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
  }

function processQuote() {

  var pricePerNight = document.getElementById('price').value;
  pricePerNight = Number(pricePerNight);

  var totalNights = document.getElementById('nights').value;
  totalNights = Number(totalNights);

  var validPrice = validateInput(pricePerNight);
  var validNights = validateInput(totalNights);

  if (validPrice == true && validNights == true) {
    var standardCost = calcStayCost(pricePerNight, totalNights);
    var standardCostOut = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = "The standard cost of stay is: $" + standardCost;
    var discountAmount = calcDiscount(totalNights, standardCost);
    var totalAmountDue = calcAmount(standardCost, discountAmount);
    var discountOut = document.getElementById('discount').innerHTML = "The total discount amount is: $" + discountAmount;
    var totalDueOut = document.getElementById('amount').innerHTML = "The total amount due is: $" + totalAmountDue;
  }

  else {
    if (validPrice == false) {
      var priceErrorOut = document.getElementById('priceErrorMessage').innerHTML = "The price" + pricePerNight + "you entered is invalid, please enter a value greater than $0";
    }
    if (validNights == false) {
      var nightsErrorOut = document.getElementById('nightsErrorMessage').innerHTML = "The number of nights you entered is invalid, please enter a value of 1 or more"
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('send');
  btn.onclick = processQuote;
}
```

End of JavaScript Code. The following is the HTML script:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Quote calculator" />
  <meta name="keywords"    content="quote, calculator, javascript, html" />
  <meta name="author"      content="Mario Stavreski" />
  <title>Testing output</title>
  <script src="w4P1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<article>

  <h2> Accomodation Quote </h2>
  <form>
    <label> Price Per Night: <input type="text" id="pricePerNight" /> </label>
    <label> Number of Nights <input type="text" id="noNights" /> </label>
    <button type="button" id="send"> Submit </button>
  </form>

  <p id="price"></p>
  <p id="discount"></p>
  <p id="amount"></p>

  <p id="priceErrorMessage"></p>
  <p id="nightsErrorMessage"></p>


</article>
<footer><p>Produced by Mario Stavreski</p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be calling your `init()` method anywhere to actually bind the onSubmit hanlder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either call `init()` to actually trigger the method so that the onSubmit handler gets bound to your button or alternatively, you can bind it within the HTML like so

```
<form onsubmit="processQuote()">
    <label> Price Per Night: <input type="text" id="pricePerNight" /> </label>
    <label> Number of Nights <input type="text" id="noNights" /> </label>
    <button type="submit" id="send"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Note I change the button type to submit so that it submits the form when clicked

Comment: I have added that but the code is still not working :/, not displaying any errors either

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is nullw4P1.js:48:30
    processQuote file:///C:/Users/stavr/Desktop/Programming Concepts/Week/w4P1.js:48
    onsubmit file:///C:/Users/stavr/Desktop/Programming Concepts/Week/w4P.html:1

Comment: Might be because you're calling your script in the head of your HTML. Your javascript is potentially running before the HTML exists. Try moving `<script src="w4P1.js"></script>` to just before your closing </body> tag. And you could also try adding a `defer` attribute to your script tag like so `<script defer src="w4P1.js"></script>`.  It indicates to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed

Comment: Update: the error I am getting seems to be that the value of var pricePerNight is NaN, but i dont know why

Comment: Your pricePerNight variable is trying to get the value from the element with the id = price. There is no value in that field as it is a  <p> tag. I think you want 'var pricePerNight = document.getElementById('pricePerNight').value'